# RestKit: How to pass additional parameters when using `postObject: usingBlock:`

Tags: ios, restkit

I do a POST like this:

```
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:object
                                 usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
                                     loader.objectMapping = objectMapping;
                                     loader.delegate = self;
                                 }];
```

How do I add an additional parameter that is not related to `objectMapping`?  In my case, I want to pass a flag to my server and set it to `true`.